# Error while creating new track in track object

Tags: trigger

I have Created three Custom object.
    1.Song 
       With fields
        Song Name     (Name field)
        Artist        (Text field)
        Length (m)    (Number field)
        Genre         (Picklist field)
        Track Count   (Number field)
        Track Licenses(Number field)
    2.Mix
      With fields
        Mix Name    (Name Field)
        Customer    (Lookup to contact) 
        Primary Genre   (Text field)
        Secondary Genre (Text field)
    3.Track
      With fields
        Track Auto Number(Name field)
        Mix     (Master-Detail )
        Song        (Lookup to song)

Now i am first Creating Trigger on track object named "TrackTrigger".
  With methods
     1.after insert-
       In this method i have to 
          Update Primary and secondary Genre in Mix obj whenever there is entry    in track object.So i have wriiten below code but stucked with error
"**Invalid field Genre__c for SObject AggregateResult"**.......
Any help is appreciated

Plz review my below code

trigger TrackTrigger on Track__c (after insert, before delete ) {
    if(trigger.isInsert){
        Set mixIdSet = new Set();
        Set songIdSet = new Set();
        List  aggrs;
        for(Track__c trackvar:Trigger.new){
            mixIdSet.add(trackvar.Mix__c);
            songIdSet.add(trackvar.Song__c);
        }

```
    Map <Id,Mix__c> mixMap = new Map <Id,Mix__c>();
    Mix__c mixVar=([SELECT Id,Name,Customer__c,Primary_Genre__c,Secondary_Genre__c 
                     FROM  Mix__c 
                     where Id IN:mixIdSet]);
    mixMap.put(mixVar.id,mixVar);

    Map <Id,Song__c> songMap = new Map <Id,Song__c>();
    Song__c songVar=([SELECT Id,Name,Artist__c,Length_min__c,Genre__c,Track_Count__c,Track_Licenses__c
                      FROM  Song__c 
                      where Id IN:songIdSet]);
    songMap.put(songVar.id,songVar);


    aggrs=([SELECT  Mix__r.Name Mixname, Song__r.Genre__c genre,COUNT(Song__r.Id) 
           FROM Track__c 
           GROUP BY Song__r.Genre__c  ,Mix__r.Name 
           ORDER BY Mix__r.Name asc, COUNT(Song__r.Id) desc]);


    for(Id idSobj :mixIdSet ){
        Integer tempCount=0;
        Mix__c tempmixvar=mixMap.get('Id');

        for(AggregateResult aggrsvar : aggrs){
            if(tempmixvar==aggrsvar.Id){
                if(tempCount==0){
                tempmixvar.Primary_Genre__c=aggrsvar.Genre__c;
                tempCount++;
                }   
                if(tempCount==1){
                tempmixvar.Secondary_Genre__c=aggrsvar.Genre__c;
                tempCount++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As the error says to you your field Genre__c is not in your object aggrsvar, you will need to change your code `aggrsvar.Genre__c` for the following `aggrsvar.Song__r.Genre__c`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you cannot access Genre__c field of Song__c object from Track__c object, so you need to change your code

`tempmixvar.Primary_Genre__c=aggrsvar.Genre__c;`

to

`tempmixvar.Primary_Genre__c=aggrsvar.Song__r.Genre__c;`

and

`tempmixvar.Secondary_Genre__c=aggrsvar.Genre__c;`

to

`tempmixvar.Secondary_Genre__c=aggrsvar.Song__r.Genre__c;`

Hope this fix your issue.